# Why can't president Trump just ask the NSA for the emails that Hillary deleted?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, hillary-clinton, surveillance, nsa

Since we know that the [NSA collects internet traffic and email](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/jun/27/nsa-data-mining-authorised-obama), why can't president Trump just ask the NSA for a copy of Hillary's deleted emails? They weren't on an encrypted government system so would have looked like private citizen emails.

A NSA worker also claims it's possible: http://www.breitbart.com/jerusalem/2016/07/31/exclusive-nsa-architect-agency-clintons-deleted-emails/

Comment: It appears Trump gets more mileage out of the belief of a scandal rather than proof of a scandal.

Comment: @blip: And far more than he would get from proof that there was nothing wrong in those emails.

Comment: If we take the NSA's word for it, they don't "collect" the data, only the meta-data, for US citizens. So no email contents, just who sent who something. Actually "collect" is an euphemism here, because they save all the data, but just have software stops that prevent full-text searching in US emails (so they  comply with the US law.) So having the data is not the same as being able to access it, strangely enough.

Comment: So... I haven't the foggiest if the FBI could subpoena the NSA for something the latter is not allowed to access (and in theory not even have). I guess the NSA would refuse the subpoena. The question is too speculative, methinks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He could, but it would be a waste of time:

- Hillary Clinton is no longer a politically relevant opponent. Trump has little to gain by persecuting her further. He has more important opponents to deal with.
- Even if there is something to find, what the NSA does is warrantless wiretapping. Whatever information is obtain that way is inadmissible in a court of law. It could be used to sway the public opinion, but as previously mentioned there is little reason to do that.
- It would look dangerously similar to the actions of Richard Nixon. Nixon also used federal law enforcement and intelligence resources to harass and surveil political opponents. When this became public, it became known as the [Watergate Scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal). Nixon was forced to resign.

Comment: I agree with bullet point one on the surface but...if you watch Fox News or read Trump's Tweets, apparently not everyone agrees. Seems there is still some 'strategy' in play to keep attacking her.

Comment: Actually, I think the first bullet point gets things backwards. Trump is clearly trying to gain by persecuting Hilary Clinton and that's precisely why he has no reason to seriously look for the emails. If they were found, there is a significant risk they would reveal nothing. But not looking for them keeps that talking point alive.

Comment: Yet he continues to persecute her, even today. https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1020008975922810883

Comment: @Relaxed Trump doesn't need to ask the NSA for the emails. Wikileaks released 30'000 of them and they found plenty.

Comment: @Basti Who found what? Trump likes to pretend there are other emails missing...